# Vim Scrolling in ConEmu

Tags: vim, conemu

I have been trying to get Scrolling (via the mouse scroll wheel) in ViM (not GVIM) on Windows to work for some time now and have been entirely unsuccessful.

I have ANSI enabled in ConEmu and the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
if !has("gui_running")
    " set term=xterm
    set mouse=a
    set nocompatible
    inoremap <Esc>[62~ <C-X><C-E>
    inoremap <Esc>[63~ <C-X><C-Y>
    nnoremap <Esc>[62~ <C-E>
    nnoremap <Esc>[63~ <C-Y>
endif
```

I've tried with and without `set term=xterm` commented, with term set to `xterm` no coloring works in ViM. I can move the cursor on the line by clicking in ViM.

I have tried executing ViM directly as a task within ConEmu (running directly under *conhost*) and normally under *Powershell*.

Also, I've tried the newest ViM (8.0-142 x64) and the newest 7.4 x86 as well.

I tried with and without plugins on vim, and a blank/default configuration on ConEmu to cover all my bases.

I am not sure where to go from here? Ideas? Also, is it possible to *view the raw ANSI from the mouse*? I know I can do this for keyboard input from the `debug > input menu`, but not for mouse input. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks - Eric

Comment: https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu/issues/1007